# Error with Libre Office - SSL and gmail

Tags: email, ssl, mailmerge, libreoffice-writer

Network connection working but outgoing server not under Libre Office -  4.4.7.2 version. Any help with this?

```
LibreOffice could not connect to the outgoing mail server. Check your system's settings and the settings in LibreOffice. Check the server name, the port and the secure connections settings
--
<class 'smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected'>: Connection unexpectedly closed, traceback follows
  C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program\python-core-3.3.3\lib\smtplib.py:375 in function getreply() [raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program\python-core-3.3.3\lib\smtplib.py:322 in function connect() [(code, msg) = self.getreply()]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program\python-core-3.3.3\lib\smtplib.py:241 in function __init__() [(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program\mailmerge.py:100 in function connect() [self.server = smtplib.SMTP(server, port,timeout=tout)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LibreOffice 6.0.2.1

1. Tick SSL but use Port 587 [would normally be for tls](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=de)
2. Allow access for less safe apps in your gmail security settings

Worked for my account although I wonder how safe it is to allow "less secure apps"

Answer (score 0):

Since 2013, LibreOffice Writer has a [known bug](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63388) regarding the mail merge wizard: Sending merged mails using a SSL connection to the SMTP server will fail.

There’s a workaround (thanks to [Andrea Tessadri](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63388#c6)) – one has to edit the python script responsible for sending the mails. It’s called `mailmerge.py`, and you’ll find it (on a linux box) under `/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/`, and on a windox box, it's located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program` (see the last line of the error message).

To make sending mails using SSL work, make sure that no LO process is running (check quickstart!). Now, open `/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/mailmerge.py` (on Linux: with root privileges), search for the line

```py
self.server = smtplib.SMTP(server, port,timeout=tout)
```

and replace it by

```
self.server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(server, port,timeout=tout)
```

Now, when sending merged documents via mail, don’t enable SSL in the mail settings; just set the port to 465. Now, sending merged documents as mail should work.

Comment: <class 'AttributeError'>: 'module' object has no attribute 'SMTP_SSL', traceback follows C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program\mailmerge.py:100 in function connect() [self.server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(server, port,timeout=tout)]

Comment: Hmm - is this a plain vanilla LibreOffice installation? Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545442/sorry-unexpected-error-module-object-has-no-attribute-smtp-ssl ? I've "repaired" different LO installations using the modification i've described, and i've never encountered that error...

Comment: Did you apply more modifications to the mailmerge script than i've proposed? Please compare with https://docs.libreoffice.org/scripting/html/mailmerge_8py_source.html

Comment: I try to use SMTP_SSL - not working , I change back SMTP, then used Update All from menu and I got the last error with <class 'Atribute..., also I put  this issue at ask.libreoffice website. I hope will fix that because use a old python-core-3.3.3 maybe because uno python module.

Comment: I'm not sure about "update all" - to which menu dies that belong?

Comment: ah - that' strange - why does updating fields and so on issue a SSL request? Sorry, i fear i can't help with this - at least wiithout knowing your document. Is there a way to provide a minimal test example?